# Composer nao esta funcionando

Tags: php, composer

Boa Tarde!

Alguém poderia me ajudar com o composer? Eu instalei aqui no Windows porém não está sendo possível usar, foi criado uma pasta no Disco C chamada "composer" com três arquivos...

Porém se eu abro o cmd dentro dessa pasta consigo usar o composer normalmente, mas se abro em outra já não consigo usar o comando...

Já adicionei A variável em Path usando "C:\composer", reiniciei o PC, já vi inúmeros tutoriais pra instalar de forma global mas mesmo assim não está funcionando, alguém poderia me dizer o que estou fazendo errado?

Dentro da pasta C:\composer

Tem dois arquivos denominados "Composer" e um composer.phar

Não consigo enxergar o que está errado...

Comment: Você já perguntou isso. Queira ler as orientações dadas na [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/571609/70) - Para evitar duplicação de informações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas está funcional na postagem linkada.